# not able to get .env variable value in react js

Tags: reactjs, dotenv

when i tried to get the value from .env file, it says undefined, i have defined variable in .env `API_URL`, is there anything which i am missing in react js ? i am using dotenv npm, can anyone please help me how to resolve this issue ? here i have uploaded my code, any help will be really appreciated

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const fs = require('fs');
alert(process.env.API_URL);
```

.env

```
API_URL=https://********/api/v1/
```

Comment: If its create react app with no webpack ejected, then env variables have to be prefixed with **REACT_APP**, so you should have **REACT_APP_API_URL** env variable and you do not need dotenv to get those variables. More info [Create react app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/)

Answer (score 3):

The two important things to remember when defining Environment Variables in your react project

1. Always reload your application after making a change to the .env file
2. Always prefix your variables with REACT_APP_

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the .env file is in the root folder of working directory

**As per the react documentation :**
You must create custom environment variables beginning with **REACT_APP_**. Any other variables except NODE_ENV will be ignored to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name. Changing any environment variables will require you to restart the development server if it is running.

Comment: it is in root folder

Comment: It is not React documentation but CRA documentation. React does not require **REACT_APP** prefix, it is CRA that requires the prefix. Your solution may work (if the app is CRA) but it is misleading, so please fix the issue in your answer.

Comment: I thought you started using create react app as Nikul Panchal said is what exactly i was trying to say!